# Fix symmetry before retopology

Tags: modeling

Given a model that was symmetrical but who now no longer is. Is there a way to delete half the model and remirror or to straighten the symmetry out.

[image: woops]

You can see in orthographic mode that the top (and front) of the model now no longer aligns with the z axis but the middle does.

There is a multi res modifier on it at the moment in case that makes any difference.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

- This will almost certainly screw up your Multires modifier, so apply it.
- Select a vertex on the one half—say the left one—and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to select everything connected to it.
- Delete it with <kbd>X</kbd>.
- Move the boundary of the top section to align with the Z-axis.

  - You can try <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>X</kbd><kbd>0</kbd> and then setting X to 0 in the transform properties, you'll probably still have some cleanup to do even if you use proportional editing.
- Go out of edit mode and use a mirror modifier. (If I remember correctly, there's a Remove Doubles option you should use.)

Comment: Applying the multires modifier crashes my laptop or when it doesn't it makes it unusably slow.  :(

Comment: Hm. Are you sculpting? Try the Apply Base button and then either just removing the modifier, or stepping down the resolution and then applying it. (The reason I said to apply it in the answer was because I didn't want you to lose all your sculpting work.)

Comment: Thanks seaturtle I've voted you up but i'm just simply not going to be able to remove half after the modifier is applied. Theres 5 levels of subdiv here. I can remove the edges in edit mode like the top pic anything above that and its hard to even see what the central vertx loop is.

Comment: Hm. Does stepping it down before applying it help? How about orthographic mode (`Num1` then `Num5`)?

Comment: Wireframe just displays as a solid outline thats how dense the subdiv was.  I've removed half in edit mode for the moment but accidently saved over origional file.

Comment: Blender saves backups (by default, only one), named `.blend1`, `.blend2`, etc. Hopefully one of those will be the original file you need.

Answer (score 1):

Idk if this can work for you, but there's also an edit mode "symmetrize" tool that can help to make a mesh symmetric in another way:

eg: from this

[image]

you get this

[image]

Comment: Thanks I tried that it seemed to mirror on top of itself.